# Trivial complex analysis proof

Tags: complex-analysis

Question: Prove that if $z, w, v ∈ C$ and $zwv = 0$ then at least one of $z$, $w$ and $v$ must be $0$.

My thought was that first, I would assume that $zwv=0$ and that $z,w,v\neq0$ This leads to a contradiction but this seems like it is too simple of a proof. I was wondering if there was a more rigorous way to show that this is true.

Any help on this is very much welcome.

Comment: Multiply the whole thing by its conjugate, that is, $\bar{z}, \bar{w}$, and $\bar{v}$.

Comment: If $z,w,v\ne 0$, then $1/z,1/w,1/v$ exist and if we multiply $zwv$ by $1/z,1/w$ and  $1/v$ we obtain 1.

Comment: Nothing is trivial, maybe you can say: "everything is formal".

Answer (score 3):

Multiply the whole thing by the conjugates $\bar{z}, \bar{w}$, $\bar{v}$ which yields,$$|z|^2 |w|^2 |v|^2 = 0.$$

Without any loss of generality, divide by $|z|^2 |w|^2$ (assume $z, w \neq 0$, else done). So we get $|v|^2 = 0 \implies |v| = 0 \implies \Re(v) = \Im(v) = 0.$

Answer (score 3):

This much is true in *any* field (in fact, in any Integral Domain). Suppose that $\;z,w\neq 0\;$ , so that there exist $\;z^{-1}\,,\,\,w^{-1}\;$ , and thus:

$$0=zwv\implies 0=z^{-1}w^{1}\cdot0=z^{-1}w^{-1}wzv=1\cdot v=v$$

and we're done.

We've used that $\;0\cdot a=0\;\;\;\forall\,a\in\Bbb F=$ any field, proven by

$$0\cdot a=(0+0)a=0\cdot a +0\cdot a\stackrel{-o\cdot a\;\text{in both sides}}\implies 0=0\cdot a$$